# GInfoWindowTab function equivalent in Google Map API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there any function in Google Map API Version to show the multiple tab info windows like the following example?

[Example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_map10.htm)

This example is done by using Google Map API Version 2.  I am wondering the equivalent function in Google Map API v3.  I can only find the google.maps.InfoWindow which is the popup window without Tab.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V3 does not have tabbed infowindows, yet.

Answer (score 2):

in this 
[GInfoWindowTab equivalent in Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389778/ginfowindowtab-equivalent-in-google-maps-api-v3)

we have this:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html