# GInfoWindowTab equivalent in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

In Google Maps API v2: **[GInfoWindowTab](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/02/working-with-info-windows-in-google-maps/#tabs)**(title,content) - to split information in the popup-windows into parts.

For example:

```js
tab1 = new GInfoWindowTab('Tab 1', 'Content of tab 1');
tab2 = new GInfoWindowTab('Tab 2', 'Content of tab 2');
```

and so on.

In Google Maps API v3 this function doesn't work.

And there isn't such function in the latest corresponding official reference:
http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow

Does anybody know, how to replace that function or imitate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The InfoBubble utility library (a library that sits on top of Maps API V3) provides this functionality.

See:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html